# Evaluating $\int\frac{x\sin^{-1}(x)}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

How can we evaluate:

$$\int\frac{x\sin^{-1}(x)}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}\mathrm{d}x$$

I tried to use integration by parts, but the positive sign of the $x^2$ in the square root doesn't cancel with the integral of $\sin^{-1}(x)$, so how can I proceed ?

Comment: Use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts setting $$\frac x{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$ as the second term whose integration is known

Comment: ,May I know the source of the problem? Also are you sure about the validity of the question as the reason explained in my answer

Answer (score 5):

Yes, integration by parts is the route to go...

Try putting $u = \sin^{-1} x \implies du = \dfrac {dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

and put $dv = \dfrac x{\sqrt{1 + x^2}}\implies v = \sqrt{1 + x^2}$

$$I = uv - \int u'v$$

Comment: have you reached the end?

Comment: $$"\ldots-\int u'v\;\;\ldots "$$

Comment: I like that notation better, thanks @DonAntonio

Comment: Has anybody reached the destination following this method?

Comment: As far as possible with elementary functions I believe that's all there is. The solution seems to involve elliptic integrals or some ohte beast like that. Anyway, changing the function that has to be integrated, after the OP already pointed out his/her problem about it, isn't a solution, imo. BTW, +1

Comment: yes, i reach sqrt 1+x^2 arcsin x-integral sqrt 1+x^2/sqrt 1-x^2. but i dont know how to integrate the fraction of sqrt 1+x^2/ sqrt 1-x^2.

Comment: @amWhy: Needs another UV as it looks like this is as good as it gets on this one +1

Comment: I agree with Amzoti+1

Answer (score 0):

$\int\dfrac{x\sin^{-1}x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx$

$=\int\dfrac{\sin^{-1}x}{2\sqrt{1+x^2}}d(x^2)$

$=\int\sin^{-1}x~d(\sqrt{1+x^2})$

$=\sqrt{1+x^2}\sin^{-1}x-\int\sqrt{1+x^2}~d(\sin^{-1}x)$

$=\sqrt{1+x^2}\sin^{-1}x-\int\dfrac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$

$=\sqrt{1+x^2}\sin^{-1}x-\int\dfrac{\sqrt{1+\sin^2u}}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2u}}d(\sin u)$ $(\text{Let}~x=\sin u)$

$=\sqrt{1+x^2}\sin^{-1}x-\int\sqrt{1+\sin^2u}~du$

$=\sqrt{1+x^2}\sin^{-1}x-\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!\sin^{2n}u}{4^n(n!)^2(1-2n)}du$

$=\sqrt{1+x^2}\sin^{-1}x-\int\left(1+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!\sin^{2n}u}{4^n(n!)^2(1-2n)}\right)du$

For $\int\sin^{2n}u~du$ , where $n$ is any natural number,

$\int\sin^{2n}u~du=\dfrac{(2n)!u}{4^n(n!)^2}-\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{(2n)!((k-1)!)^2\sin^{2k-1}u\cos u}{4^{n-k+1}(n!)^2(2k-1)!}+C$

This result can be done by successive integration by parts from the formula of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_trigonometric_functions.

$\therefore\sqrt{1+x^2}\sin^{-1}x-\int\left(1+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!\sin^{2n}u}{4^n(n!)^2(1-2n)}\right)du$

$=\sqrt{1+x^2}\sin^{-1}x-u-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n((2n)!)^2u}{16^n(n!)^4(1-2n)}-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{(-1)^n((2n)!)^2((k-1)!)^2\sin^{2k-1}u\cos u}{4^{2n-k+1}(n!)^4(2k-1)!(1-2n)}+C$

$=\sqrt{1+x^2}\sin^{-1}x-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n((2n)!)^2u}{16^n(n!)^4(1-2n)}-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{(-1)^n((2n)!)^2((k-1)!)^2\sin^{2k-1}u\cos u}{4^{2n-k+1}(n!)^4(2k-1)!(1-2n)}+C$

$=\sqrt{1+x^2}\sin^{-1}x-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n((2n)!)^2\sin^{-1}x}{16^n(n!)^4(1-2n)}-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{(-1)^n((2n)!)^2((k-1)!)^2x^{2k-1}\sqrt{1-x^2}}{4^{2n-k+1}(n!)^4(2k-1)!(1-2n)}+C$

Answer (score -1):

As the existing integral is not [elementary](http://goo.gl/irflWX)

I assume the Question to be $$I=\int\frac{x\sin^{-1}x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$

Setting  $\sin^{-1}x=\phi\implies \sin\phi=x, \cos\phi=+\sqrt{1-x^2}$ as the principal value of $\sin^{-1}x$ lies in $\left[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right]$

$$I=\int\phi\sin\phi d\phi $$

Now integrate by parts $$I=\int\phi\sin\phi d\phi=\phi\int\sin\phi d\phi-\int\left(\frac{d\phi}{d\phi}\cdot\int\sin\phi d\phi\right)d\phi $$

$$=-\phi\cdot\cos\phi+\int \cos\phi d\phi=\cdots$$

Comment: the question is sqrt 1+x^2, is positive instead of negative

Comment: @user118035, that's why find my comment in the original Question?

Comment: i get -arcsin x sqrt 1-x^2 + x + constant

Comment: @user118035, If you have meant $$-\arcsin x\cdot\sqrt{1-x^2}+x,$$ its derivative is not $$ \frac{x \sin^{-1}(x)}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}$$

Comment: i follow the step from your equation integrate of cos = sin, and substitute in the value...i'm a bit lost now.

Comment: @user118035, sorry for the delay. But first of all, please answer my query in the Question. Btw, do you know Integration by parts, I have set $\sin\phi$ as the second term

Comment: yes, i understand by parts and the way you have made the second term 

= -θ cos θ + integral cos θ
= -θ cos θ + sin θ

From the second term equation, θ=arcsin x; cos θ= sqrt 1-x^2; sub the value into the equation.

= -arcsin x (sqrt 1-x^2) - x + Constant